# text_field disabled in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code to disable a `text_field` when a user is not an admin and it is working fine:

```
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :nome, "Genero" %>
<%= f.text_field :nome, class: "form-control", disabled: true if not is_admin? %>
</div>
```

But when a user is an admin the `text_field` just disappears.  Does anyone know why this is happening and what I have to do?

Comment: No error message in the console? If it the condition *isn't* true? Why not just use `disabled: !is_admin?`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Assuming that `is_admin?` returns `true` or `false`, you can simply do

```
<%= f.text_field :nome, class: "form-control", disabled: !is_admin? %>
```

Currently, the *if condition* i.e., `if not is_admin?` is applied on the entire text field, which results in text field disappearance when `is_admin?` returns `true` and when the condition returns `false` text field is displayed.

Comment: Thanks! That worked, I wonder why `disabled: true if not is_admin` messed up when I was logged with the admin account.

Comment: I actually explained the reason in the answer. Its like `if condition` is acting as a modifier on text field, so text field would only be displayed when condition in `if condition` is `true`, the condition in your case was `if not is_admin?`. When logged in with admin account, `is_admin?` returns `true`, so `not is_admin?` becomes `false` which is why text field is not shown as condition is `false`.

Answer (score 5):

The specific reason that your code wasn't working as expected is an operator precedence issue - the `if` test is being applied to the whole text field, not just the `disabled` parameter.

The most direct solution to this (though not necessarily the best) is to wrap `true if not is_admin?` in parentheses:

```
<%= f.text_field :nome, class: "form-control", disabled: (true if not is_admin?) %>
```

Otherwise, the whole text field has the `if` applied to it, like this:

```
<%= (f.text_field :nome, class: "form-control", disabled: true) if not is_admin? %>
```

So it will be rendered only for *non-admin* users - i.e. when `is_admin?` is false.

Also, when it's rendered, it will always be `disabled`.  (Which on the plus side, will make it harder for non-admins to abuse.)